# Bootstrap Switch, how to remove the outline of the switcher

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-switch

I am using bootstrap-switch - v3.3.1, but I don't need the defaulted blue outline of the switcher when swithing[image], I set `style="outline: 0 none;` for the input but it does not work.

Here is my html:

```
            <div class="switch" style="display:inline-block;>
                <input id="accu-switcher" type="checkbox" style="outline: 0 none;" checked data-label-text="TEXT"/>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
 $('#accu-switcher').bootstrapSwitch({size: "mini",state: false});
        $('.module .switch').css("visibility","visible");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update this css class or override it to:

```
.bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-focused
{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
.bootstrap-switch:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap switch has the following css which is responsible for the glow and `outline: none;` alone will not remove it . ([Bootstrap switch css file](https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css#L181))

```
.bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-focused {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

Something like this should do it

```
.bootstrap-switch{
  border-color: #66afe9; /*you can change this depending on your application's background color */
  outline: 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Here is a ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/g8d6cxz9/1/)***